# How to add extra privilages for my Symfony 2 ACL's

Tags: symfony, acl

Symfony provides various privileges like view, edit, delete, owner etc. How do I add more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them together and then different combinations will give different number of mask.

[List of available masks](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Permission/MaskBuilder.php).

And at the top of class in commentary you can see example.